# convert a django queryset into an array

Tags: python, arrays, django, django-models

i would like convert a django queryset into an array like,

```
firstnames=Users.objects.values('firstnames')
```

to get a result that looks like

```
firstnames = ["Nancy", "Andrew", "Janet", "Margaret", "Steven", "Michael", "Robert", "Laura", "Anne"];
```

Any insights please?
Regards
Josh

Answer (score 37):

Use [`QuerySet.values_list`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/) and specify `flat=True`:

```
firstnames = Users.objects.values_list('firstnames', flat=True)
firstnames = list(firstnames)
```

Comment: Hi falsetru,I get an error Manager object has no attribute value_list

Comment: @user3262370, It is `values_list`, not `value_list`.

Comment: I tried this with decimal values, the returned list contains strings: Decimal('50.00'), Decimal('100.00')?? How do I just get the values?

Comment: @almostabeginner, They are not strings. The representation of decimal objects looks like so. Try `int(Decimal('50.00'))` or `float(Decimal('50.00'))` according to your need.

Comment: With values_list you get a Queryset... containing a list :  <QuerySet [... , ...]> So you must be aware that you can't really use your result as a list (for example add your 'list' to another list).

Comment: @G.Lebret, That's why there's `list(firstnames)` in the code of this answer :)

Answer (score 1):

```
def get_array(Table, column):
    rows = Table.objects.values(column)
    return [row[column] for row in rows]

print get_array(Users, 'firstnames')
```

Comment: Use value_list() instead and select only the columns you need

Comment: In some abstractions, it may not make sense to limit columns. For simple use cases what you say is a good general rule.