# Django + chart.js: plot with django Queryset data

Tags: javascript, python, django, chart.js

I am across a problem that I cannot handle. I passing queryset data from a django view to its corresponding template and I want to use this data to plot a graph with chart.js

I am trying to achieve this without using Ajax requests.

However, when I try to acquire the queryset data with javascript to pass it in chart.js it renders an error.

Here is what I have done in html:

```
<div id="default_data">
                      <p>  {{ default_items }} </p>
                 </div>
                 <div id="labels">
                   
                 <p>{{ labels }} </p>
<div class="col-lg-6">
                      <div id="tag3" class="card-footer small text-muted">{% trans 'ITEMS WITH HIGHEST NUMBER OF SALES (3 MONTHS)' %}</div>
                <div class="bar-chart block">
                  <canvas id="myChart3" height="90"></canvas>
                </div>
              </div>
```

and here is what `labels` and `default_data` render:

```
<QuerySet [58.0, 62.0, 74.0, 60.0, 16.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 2.0]>

<QuerySet ['372750', '372600', '372650', '372700', '372150', '289807', '289922', '289840', '289923', '372310']>
```

and javascript:

```
  <script>
       
      
      
              
                    var ctx3 = document.getElementById('myChart3').getContext('2d');
                    var labels = document.getElementById("labels");
                  

                
                
                var myChart3 = new Chart(ctx3, {
                        type: 'bar',
                        data: {
                            labels: labels,
                            datasets: [{
                                label:'références avec nombre de ventes élevé',
                                data: default_data,
                                 label: '# of Votes',
                          
                                borderWidth: 1,
                            }]
                        },
                            options: {
                                scales: {
                                    yAxes: [{
                                      
                                          ticks: {
                                            beginAtZero: true
                                        }

                                            
                                    }]
                                }
                            
                        }
                    });
      
    </script>
```

I don't understand the error that gets outputed in chrome dev:

```
Chart.min.js:10 Uncaught TypeError: e.slice is not a function
```

Can someone explain me how to pass django Queryset data in chart.js without using ajax requests?

Comment: probably the default_data that you are passing to the chart object is not an array and data key in chart options expects it to be an array.

Comment: I am not sure because in the chart.js documentation, they show example with passing lists: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/

Comment: [1,2,3,....] -> This represents an array in JavaScript. As per the docs, you need an array. I haven't worked on Django but this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21947237/convert-a-django-queryset-into-an-array

Comment: I was able to generate an array using the link that you shared but unfortunately it still does not work

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: the same error, as well as the following: ```Chart.min.js:10 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'skip' of element undefined```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224342/discussion-between-maharshi-rawal-and-peyo).